# ${\displaystyle \int_{0}^{7}f^{(7)}(x)(x-1)^6dx}$ where $f(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\sin(x)$ for $x>0$ and $f(0)=0$.

Tags: integration

> How to find the below integral: $$\int_{0}^{1}f^{(7)}(x)(x-1)^6dx$$ where $f(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\sin(x)$ for $x>0$ and $f(0)=0$.

My attempt:

I tried to find the derivative $f^{(7)}(x)$, but at $f^{(3)}(x)$ itself the derivative becomes very complex and I think this will take too long to find the above integral.
$$f^{(3)}(x)=-\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}((6x^6-24x^4+36x^2-8)\sin(x)+(x^9+18x^5-12x^3)\cos(x))}{x^9}$$ 
Please help me in solving this question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it's meant being taking $7$ times by parts, but then you'll have to $f^{(6)},\ldots ,f'$ somehow. Also consider $\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin I think it will get only more complicated if I get that way, I also thought of the same, but it was easier to do the above. Doing parts will get me to solve many many integrals. I think there has to be some shorter method.

Comment: Mathematica says that the answer is $-\frac{144 (236960845618601179 \sin (7)+291324373323376638 \cos (7))}{1628413597910449 \sqrt[49]{e}}$.

Comment: That is some crazy crazy expression.

Comment: Are you sure the upper limit is $7$ and not $1$? In the case of $1$, the by parts method will be very easy.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat sorry my mistake. I have edited the same.

Comment: I hope you can solve it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integration by parts is definitely the way to go. We have an integral of the form
$$\int_0^7 f^{(7)}(x)g(x) \; \mathrm{d}x,$$
where $g(x)$ is differentiable, and $g^{(7)}$ is constantly $0$. So,
\begin{align*}
\int_0^7 f^{(7)}(x) g(x) \; \mathrm{d}x &= [f^{(6)}(x)g(x)]_0^7 - \int_0^7 f^{(6)}(x) g'(x) \; \mathrm{d}x \\
&= [f^{(6)}(x)g(x)]_0^7 - [f^{(5)}(x)g'(x)]_0^7 + \int_0^7 f^{(5)}(x) g''(x) \; \mathrm{d}x \\
&= [f^{(6)}(x)g(x)]_0^7 - [f^{(5)}(x)g'(x)]_0^7 + [f^{(4)}(x)g''(x)]_0^7 - \int_0^7 f^{(5)}(x) g^{(3)}(x) \; \mathrm{d}x \\
&\vdots \\
&= [f^{(6)}(x)g(x)]_0^7 - [f^{(5)}(x)g'(x)]_0^7 + [f^{(4)}(x)g''(x)]_0^7 - [f^{(3)}(x)g^{(3)}(x)] \\
&+ [f''(x)g^{(4)}(x)]_0^7 - [f'(x)g^{(5)}(x)]_0^7 + [f(x)g^{(6)}(x)]_0^7 - \underbrace{\int_0^7 f(x)g^{(7)}(x) \; \mathrm{d}x}_{= \;0}.
\end{align*}
The rest is tedious substitution.

Comment: There was a typo. I am sorry for the error that I had done.

Comment: Well, it doesn't change the method, but it makes the final substitution a lot easier. Note that $g(1) = g'(1) = g''(1) = \ldots = g^{(5)}(1) = 0$, and $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$ for any $n$. It therefore follows that most of the terms are $0$, except $[f(x)g^{(6)}(x)]_0^1 = e^{-1}\sin(1)$.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I didnt realise the fact that $g(1)=g'(1)=\cdots=0$. Thank you again.

Comment: @s1mple You're welcome.

Comment: $g^{(6)}(1)=720$ and f(0)=0 so, ans should be $720e^{-1}\sin(1)$ right?

Comment: Please have a look into this.

Comment: Mathematica says that the integral is $720\sin(1)/e$.

Comment: @s1mple Yep, you're right, sorry.